# gcc 4.7 about Variadic Templates/ decltype /std::forward

Tags: c++, c++11, decltype

```
    char foo()
    {
         std::cout<<"foo()"<<std::endl;
         return 'c';
    }              
    void foo(char &&i)
    {
         std::cout<<"foo(char &&i)"<<std::endl;
    }
    struct pipe {};
    template<class OP>
    struct Flow;
    template<>
    struct Flow<pipe> {
         template<class L,class R>
         static  auto apply(L&& l,R &&r)->decltype(r(std::forward<L>(l))) {
              return r(std::forward<L>(l));
         }
    };
    template<class L,class R,class E>
    struct Pipe;
    template<class F,class...ARGS>
    auto eval(F& f,ARGS&&... arg)->decltype(f(std::forward<ARGS>(arg)...))
    {
        return f(std::forward<ARGS>(arg)...);
    }
    template<class L,class R,class E,class...ARGS>
    auto eval(Pipe<L,R,E>&f,ARGS&&... arg)->decltype(Flow<E>::apply(eval(f.lhs,std::forward<ARGS>(arg)...),f.rhs))
    {
        return Flow<E>::apply(eval(f.lhs,std::forward<ARGS>(arg)...),f.rhs);
    }
    template<class L,class R,class E>
    struct Pipe {
         L lhs;
         R rhs;
         Pipe(L &l,R& r):lhs(l),rhs(r) {
         }
          template<class...ARGS>
           auto operator()(ARGS&&... arg)->decltype(eval<L,R,E >(*this,std::forward<ARGS>(arg)...)) {
                return eval<L,R,E >(*this,std::forward<ARGS>(arg)...);
           }
    };

     void streamtest()
    {

        void (*foo1)(char &&)=foo;
        void (*foo2)(int ,int ,short )=foo;
        char (*foo3)()=foo;

        Pipe<char(*)(),void(*)(char&&),pipe> pp(foo3,foo1);
        pp(1);

    }
```

I want write a pipe Library for function  transfer. but error Let me confused:

```
 \FEstream.cpp: In function 'void streamtest()':
 \FEstream.cpp:117:9: error: no match for call to '(Pipe<char (*)(), void (*)(char&&), pipe>) (int)'
 \FEstream.cpp:98:8: note: candidate is:
 \FEstream.cpp:104:13: note: template<class ... ARGS> decltype (eval<L, R, E>((* this), (forward<ARGS>)(Pipe::operator()::arg)...)) Pipe::operator()(ARGS&& ...) [with ARGS = {ARGS ...}; L = char (*)(); R = void (*)(char&&); E = pipe]
 \FEstream.cpp:104:13: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
 \FEstream.cpp: In substitution of 'template<class ... ARGS> decltype (eval<L, R, E>((* this), (forward<ARGS>)(Pipe::operator()::arg)...)) Pipe::operator()(ARGS&& ...) [with ARGS = {ARGS ...}; L = char (*)(); R = void (*)(char&&); E = pipe] [with ARGS = {int}]':
 \FEstream.cpp:117:9:   required from here
 \FEstream.cpp:104:13: error: no matching function for call to 'eval(Pipe<char (*)(), void (*)(char&&), pipe>&, int)'
 \FEstream.cpp:104:13: note: candidates are:
 \FEstream.cpp:88:6: note: template<class F, class ... ARGS> decltype (f((forward<ARGS>)(eval::arg)...)) eval(F&, ARGS&& ...)
 \FEstream.cpp:88:6: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
 \FEstream.cpp:104:13: note:   cannot convert '*(Pipe<char (*)(), void (*)(char&&), pipe>*)this' (type 'Pipe<char (*)(), void (*)(char&&), pipe>') to type 'char (*&)()'
 \FEstream.cpp:93:6: note: template<class L, class R, class E, class ... ARGS> decltype (Flow<E>::apply(eval(f.lhs, (forward<ARGS>)(eval::arg)...), f.rhs)) eval(Pipe<L, R, E>&, ARGS&& ...)
 \FEstream.cpp:93:6: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
 \FEstream.cpp: In substitution of 'template<class L, class R, class E, class ... ARGS> decltype (Flow<E>::apply(eval(f.lhs, (forward<ARGS>)(arg)...), f.rhs)) eval(Pipe<L, R, E>&, ARGS&& ...) [with L = char (*)(); R = void (*)(char&&); E = pipe; ARGS = {int}]':
 \FEstream.cpp:104:13:   required by substitution of 'template<class ... ARGS> decltype (eval<L, R, E>((* this), (forward<ARGS>)(Pipe::operator()::arg)...)) Pipe::operator()(ARGS&& ...) [with ARGS = {ARGS ...}; L = char (*)(); R = void (*)(char&&); E = pipe] [with ARGS = {int}]'
 \FEstream.cpp:117:9:   required from here
 \FEstream.cpp:93:6: error: no matching function for call to 'eval(char (*&)(), int)'
 \FEstream.cpp:93:6: note: candidate is:
 \FEstream.cpp:88:6: note: template<class F, class ... ARGS> decltype (f((forward<ARGS>)(eval::arg)...)) eval(F&, ARGS&& ...)
 \FEstream.cpp:88:6: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
 \FEstream.cpp: In substitution of 'template<class F, class ... ARGS> decltype (f((forward<ARGS>)(arg)...)) eval(F&, ARGS&& ...) [with F = char (*)(); ARGS = {int}]':
 \FEstream.cpp:93:6:   required by substitution of 'template<class L, class R, class E, class ... ARGS> decltype (Flow<E>::apply(eval(f.lhs, (forward<ARGS>)(eval::arg)...), f.rhs)) eval(Pipe<L, R, E>&, ARGS&& ...) [with L = char (*)(); R = void (*)(char&&); E = pipe; ARGS = {int}]'
 \FEstream.cpp:104:13:   required by substitution of 'template<class ... ARGS> decltype (eval<L, R, E>((* this), (forward<ARGS>)(Pipe::operator()::arg)...)) Pipe::operator()(ARGS&& ...) [with ARGS = {ARGS ...}; L = char (*)(); R = void (*)(char&&); E = pipe] [with ARGS = {int}]'
 \FEstream.cpp:117:9:   required from here
 \FEstream.cpp:88:6: error: too many arguments to function
Process terminated with status 1 (0 minutes, 0 seconds)
```

what's happening?Is it my error,or gcc's not C++11 compliant?

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

thanks Dave S.but ,code is only simplification.In fact, I use templateEval::eval:

```
template<class L,class R,class E>
struct Pipe;

template<class F>
struct Eval {
     template<class...ARGS>
     static auto eval(F&f,ARGS&&... arg)->decltype(f(std::forward<ARGS>(arg)...)) {
          return f(std::forward<ARGS>(arg)...);
     }
};
template<class L,class R,class E>
struct Eval<Pipe<L,R,E> > {
     static auto eval(Pipe<L,R,E>&f)->decltype(Flow<E>::apply(f.lhs,f.rhs)) {
          return Flow<E>::apply(f.lhs,f.rhs);
     }
     template<class...ARGS>
     static void eval(Pipe<L,R,E>&f,ARGS&&...arg) {
          static_assert(!std::is_same<E,pipe>::value,
                        "multiple input for expression\nsample: auto expr=wrap(foo1)<var1|foo2 ;call expr(var2) instead of expr()");
     }
};
template<class L,class R>
struct Eval<Pipe<L,R,pipe> > {
     template<class...ARGS>
     static auto eval(Pipe<L,R,pipe>&f,ARGS&&... arg)->decltype(Flow<pipe>::apply(Eval<L>::eval(f.lhs,std::forward<ARGS>(arg)...),f.rhs)) {
          return Flow<pipe>::apply(Eval<L>::eval(f.lhs,std::forward<ARGS>(arg)...),f.rhs);
     }
};
template<class L,class R,class E>
struct Pipe {
     L lhs;
     R rhs;
     Pipe(L &l,R& r):lhs(l),rhs(r) {
     }
  template<class...ARGS>
   auto operator()(ARGS&&... arg)->decltype(Eval<Pipe>::eval(*this,std::forward<ARGS>(arg)...)) {
        return Eval<Pipe>::eval(*this,std::forward<ARGS>(arg)...);
   }
};



         void streamtest()
        {

            void (*foo1)(char &&)=foo;
            void (*foo2)(int ,int ,short )=foo;
            char (*foo3)()=foo;

            Pipe<char(*)(),void(*)(char&&),pipe> pp(foo3,foo1);
             //pp(); //no call!
        }
```

error is:

- FEstream.cpp: In instantiation of 'struct Eval >':
- FEstream.cpp:121:9:   required from 'struct      Pipe'
- FEstream.cpp:134:45:         required from here
- FEstream.cpp:110:18:    error: invalid use of       incomplete type
  'struct Pipe'
- FEstream.cpp:115:8: error: declaration of 'struct Pipe
  void (*)(char&&), pipe>'
- FEstream.cpp:110:18: error: invalid use of     incomplete type
  'struct Pipe'
- FEstream.cpp:115:8: error: declaration of 'struct Pipe
  void (*)(char&&), pipe>'

Process terminated with status 1 (0 minutes,
   0 seconds) 6 errors, 0 warnings

Pipe::operator()(ARGS&&... arg) is a template member function.why I declaring variable Pipe(pp) Cause an error? it Should not be instantiated because I have not used it`enter code here`

---

anybody?
and I forget a status when eval function use by Pipe like

```
template<class...ARGS>
   auto operator()(ARGS&&... arg)->decltype(eval(*this,std::forward<ARGS>(arg)...)) {
        return eval(*this,std::forward<ARGS>(arg)...);
   }
```

not

```
 template<class...ARGS>
   auto operator()(ARGS&&... arg)->decltype(eval<L,R,E>(*this,std::forward<ARGS>(arg)...)) {
        return eval<L,R,E>(*this,std::forward<ARGS>(arg)...);
   }
```

will error like reece:
template instantiation depth exceeds maximum of 900 .....

Seems to be select Eval(F&....  instead of   eval(Pipe&f..... when not specify a template parameter

Answer (score 2):

It's having trouble due to an argument mismatch, somewhere in your call chain.  So, we can do it manually to find the problem.

`Pipe<char(*)(),void(*)(char&&),pipe> pp(foo3,foo1);` is using foo3, which takes 0 arguments as its `L`, and foo1, which takes an char rvalue-reference as `R`.  And `E` is your marker structure `pipe`

When invoked with the int 1.

`pp(1)` calls `eval<L,R,E>(*this, 1)`, which in turn calls

`Flow<E>::apply(eval(foo3,1),foo1)`.

First, the inner eval is called.  This attempts to determine the declval of `foo3(1)`, however, foo3 was declared to take 0 arguments.  This causes a compilation failure, which results in the substitution failures you're getting.

Edit:  With the changed question, your problem is now you're creating a specialization of `Eval` for `Pipe`, but `Eval` is attempting to use fields of `Pipe` in it's return declaration (via decltype), and `Pipe` is doing the same.  You're going to have to break that cycle so something can be defined first, or at least set it up so that the cycle isn't introduced in the function declaration, so you can define the methods after you've fully defined both types.

I'm not sure what the `Eval` class is attempting to accomplish.  One solution might be to remove that altogether and simply have `Pipe::operator()` invoke the method more directly.

Comment: +1; and I noted the helpful error message: error: no matching function for call to 'eval(char (*&)(), int)'

Comment: @aschepler, Yeah, that was my first hint, but it does appear 3 times (each time saying `no matching function call for...`.  So I wanted to trace it down.  The repeated GCC error chain is because the first failure causes it's caller to not have a return type (as if enable_if had been used), causing it's caller to return an error, and so-on.

Comment: thanks.but this is because Simplify the code bring a error.In fact I use template<class F> struct Eval::eval nor only global function eval

Answer (score 0):

I'm building this on Ubuntu with gcc 4.6 (I don't have a version of gcc 4.7 to try) so YMMV.

gcc 4.6 : `g++-4.6 -std=c++0x test.cpp`

1. `void (*foo2)(int ,int ,short )=foo;` -- there is no version of `foo` matching this signature, so I commented it out.
2. `error: expected a type, got ‘pipe’` -- `pipe` appears to be defined elsewhere, so renamed it to `pipe_`.
3. `error: invalid use of ‘this’ at top level` -- gcc 4.6 does not like `auto operator()->decltype(*this)` syntax, so replaced `*this` with `Pipe<L,R,E>(lhs,rhs)`.
4. `error: no match for call to ‘(Pipe<char (*)(), void (*)(char&&), pipe_>) (int)’` -- gcc 4.6 is failing to match the `operator()`. Here is where I am puzzled.

clang 3.1 : `clang -std=c++11 test.cpp`

1. same mismatched foo declaration as gcc
2. same "expected 'pipe' to be a type" error as gcc
3. `error: no matching function for call to object of type 'Pipe<char (*)(), void (*)(char &&), pipe_>'` when calling `operator()`

Ok. Both gcc and clang indicate an issue with the `operator()` definition.

```
template<class...ARGS>
auto operator()(ARGS&&... arg)->decltype(eval<L,R,E >(*this,std::forward<ARGS>(arg)...));
```

Here you are calling `eval` with `*this` and the forwarded arguments. There are two versions of `eval`:

```
template<class F,class...ARGS>
auto eval(F& f,ARGS&&... arg)->decltype(f(std::forward<ARGS>(arg)...));
```

and:

```
template<class L,class R,class E,class...ARGS>
auto eval(Pipe<L,R,E>&f,ARGS&&... arg)->decltype(Flow<E>::apply(eval(f.lhs,std::forward<ARGS>(arg)...),f.rhs));
```

Now, because `eval` is a function and all arguments are specified in its arguments, you don't need to specify them explicitly. Doing so like:

```
eval<L,R,E >(*this,std::forward<ARGS>(arg)...)
```

is telling the compiler that the first argument is `L` which it is not, it is `Pipe<L,R,E>`.

Changing the `operator()` definition to:

```
template<class...ARGS>
auto operator()(ARGS&&... arg)->decltype(eval(*this,std::forward<ARGS>(arg)...));
```

now crashes clang and gcc!

EDIT: Ok, now trying the new version with gcc 4.7 I now get:

```
test.cpp:30:10: error: template instantiation depth exceeds maximum of 900 (use -ftemplate-depth= to increase the maximum) substituting ‘template<class _Tp> constexpr _Tp&& std::forward(typename std::remove_reference<_Tp>::type&&) [with _Tp = int]’
test.cpp:30:10:   required by substitution of ‘template<class L, class R, class E, class ... ARGS> decltype (Flow<E>::apply(eval(f.lhs, (forward<ARGS>)(arg)...), f.rhs)) eval(Pipe<L, R, E>&, ARGS&& ...) [with L = char (*)(); R = void (*)(char&&); E = pipe_; ARGS = int]’
test.cpp:41:17:   required by substitution of ‘template<class ... ARGS> decltype (eval(Pipe(((Pipe*)this)->Pipe<L, R, E>::lhs, ((Pipe*)this)->Pipe<L, R, E>::rhs), (forward<ARGS>)(Pipe::operator()::arg)...)) Pipe::operator()(ARGS&& ...) [with ARGS = {ARGS ...}; L = char (*)(); R = void (*)(char&&); E = pipe_] [with ARGS = {int}]’
test.cpp:25:10:   required by substitution of ‘template<class F, class ... ARGS> decltype (f((forward<ARGS>)(eval::arg)...)) eval(F&, ARGS&& ...) [with F = Pipe<char (*)(), void (*)(char&&), pipe_>; ARGS = {int}]’
```

with the recursion between 41:17 (`Pipe<L,R,E>::operator()`) and 25:10 (`eval<F,ARGS>()`), so it is not picking up the `Pipe` specialization of `eval`. Now I am stuck again.

Comment: Dave S is right. I use mingw gcc 4.7  change pp(1) to pp(); enable C++11 use -std=c++11 on gcc instead of -std=c++0x